# What function corresponds to the following graph description?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

This is almost like a puzzle.

This is the graph of $\csc(x).$

[image]

Now imagine I take each half-period and rotate it $180^{\circ},$ or flip it vertically, for both operations it would be with reference to the min/max point.

What kind of function would I need to get a graph like this?

[image]

Since my example graph is not precise, any function that creates something that looks similar will do.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = -\csc(x) + 2 \sin (x)$$

Desmos plot:

[image: Desmos plot]

Comment: This formula approximates described transformation very well, however, it is not the exact solution.

Comment: From the original question: "any function that creates something that looks similar will do." I liked this one because it involved no "case" statements, and I'm guessing that OP will be using this in a computer program, so that's an advantage. But yours does in fact more closely follow OP's description of the way to get a graph that looks like the one OP wants. I think, however, there is no "exact" solution because OP explicitly says "anything close will do".

Comment: I mean that your solution is *correct* since it is *similar* function to described one in original question. Therefore, is an answer to this question. I just wanted to point it out that for somebody looking for exact representation of the described transformation.
BTW I up-voted your post.

Answer (score 2):

Note, it might be possible to find more beautiful formula, nonetheless, here it is

$$\forall_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \left\{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      -\csc{x} + 2& \textrm{for} & x \in (k\pi,(k + 1)\pi)\\
      -\csc{x} - 2 & \textrm{for} & x\in ((k+1)\pi, (k+2)\pi)
    \end{array}
\right. $$

Function prooposed by **John Hughes** is very closed to this formula, however, it is not exactly the same, and is not the exact representation of the transformation outlined in the question.

[image]

Therefore, depending on the use case you might prefer to choose one of two.